# read access violation flags=0x0 (first chance)

Tags: c++, qt

I have a function which returns float values by a `float *` pointer:

```cpp
QVector3D vertexCoordOnBuffer_float(const float *bufferPtr, 
                                    const quint64 offset, 
                                    const quint64 stride, 
                                    const quint64 vertexIndex) const
{
    if (!bufferPtr)
        return QVector3D();

    float xVal = *(bufferPtr + offset + vertexIndex * stride + 0 );
    float yVal = *(bufferPtr + offset + vertexIndex * stride + 1 );
    float zVal = *(bufferPtr + offset + vertexIndex * stride + 2 );
    QVector3D vertexCoord = QVector3D(xVal, yVal, zVal);
    return vertexCoord;
}
```

I'm  calling the function with:

```
for(quint64 i = 0; i < m_count; ++i) {

    uint vertexIdx = // ... depends on i

    QVector3D vertexCoord = QVector3D();

    vertexCoord = vertexCoordOnBuffer_float(m_posBufferPtr_float, 
                                            m_byteOffsetPos, 
                                            m_byteStridePos, 
                                            vertexIdx);
}
```

At some point on the `for` loop (when almost 10% of loop is done), I run into this exception:

[image: Exception]

I stepped through the code in debug mode but couldn't figure out the cause. I wonder if something is noticeably wrong in my code.

Comment: `vertexIdx` is probably too high and thus `xVal` and friends try to deref something that doesn't belong to `bufferPtr`.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. Does `m_posBufferPtr_float` really point to an array of floats of correct size? Why do you use pointer + size instead of a container?

Comment: Did you give values `offset`, `stride`, and `vertexIndex` in bytes or multiples of `sizeof (float)`? (The latter would be correct concerning how you access data. `m_byteOffsetPos` and `m_byteStridePos` sound somehow suspicious.)

Comment: @Scheff You solved it =) Can you post your comment as answer so that I can close this question as answered?

Comment: Actually, your question lacks enough info. It was rather a shot into blue. (I remember that I accidentally made a similar error although I was very aware of this topic.) ;-) You may make a self-answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Scheff solved the problem in a comment:

> Did you give values `offset`, `stride`, and `vertexIndex` in bytes or multiples of `sizeof (float)`? (The latter would be correct concerning how you access data. `m_byteOffsetPos` and `m_byteStridePos` sound somehow suspicious)

Problem solved with these modifications:

```cpp
uint vertexIdx = // ... Fix: consider sizeof(unsigned int) in computation

vertexCoord = vertexCoordOnBuffer_float(m_posBufferPtr_float, 
                                        m_byteOffsetPos / sizeof(float), // Fix
                                        m_byteStridePos / sizeof(float), // Fix
                                        vertexIdx);
```